# rds file decompressed has inconsistent size

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a downloaded a .rds file that I have decompressed in R using:

```
t<-readRDS("myfile.rds")
```

the file is easily decompressed into a data frame. ncol(t)=24, nrow(t)=20.
When I view the file in R studio, the table has actually 1572 columns and 20 rows.

I would like to know what I am actually dealing with here, mainly because when I try to save this data frame on a mysql server using RMySQL and DBI (dbWriteTable() ), R freezes.

For your information, class(t)='data.frame', typeof(t)='list'.

str(t) yields

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

tidyr::unnest(t) yields

[image]

thank you for your assistance

Comment: If the columns are `list` columns containing dataframes, RStudio will sometimes expand them in the Viewer (with names including dots to separate the column and sub-column names), which would look as if there are more columns than there actually are.  `str(t)` will tell you whether any of the columns are lists.

Comment: Since `t` is a small data frame, please edit your post with output of `dput(t)`. FYI - in R, `data.frame` is a class object of `list` type.

Comment: @Andrew Gustar Thank you!
str(t) indicates a lot of the columns are actually lists of 20 and some are data.frames. I think this is a case of nested tables and loops here.

Comment: @Parfait dput(t) has quite a large output.I am not sure how to efficiently display that.

Comment: @Maadscientist You can try using `dplyr::unnest` to expand the list columns into a single rectangular dataframe, that will hopefully be more compatible with your database.

Comment: Then, please [**edit**](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/67660881/edit) your post with output of `str(t)`.

Comment: Still very long output @Parfait.

Comment: @Andrew Gustar. Do you mean tidyr::unnest()?

Comment: @Maadscientist Sorry - yes - it is somewhere in the `tidyverse`!

Answer (score 1):

From your `str` call, consider walking down each nested element and flatten each one accordingly with either `[[`, `unlist`, or `cbind` to generate a main data frame. The recurring property is that most components appear to have length of 20 items, being number of observations of `t`.

```r
# FLATTEN LIST OF CHR VECTORS INTO DATA FRAME COLUMN
t$alt_names <- unlist(t$alt_names)

# FLATTEN ONE COLUMN DATA FRAME
t$official_sites <- t$official_sites[[1]]

# ADJUST COLUMNS TO ALL NAs DUE TO ALL EMPTY LISTS
t$stats$previous_seasons <- NA

# CREATE TWENTY NEW COLUMNS FROM LIST OF CHR VECTORS
t$stats[paste0("seasonGoals_away", 1:20)] <- unlist(t$stats$seasonGoals_away)
t$stats$seasonGoals_away <- NULL    # REMOVE ORIGINAL COLUMN

# SEPARATE LARGE DATA FRAME PIECES
stats <- t$stats
t$stats <- NULL                     # REMOVE ORIGINAL COLUMN

# COMBINE LARGE DATA FRAME PIECES
main_df <- cbind(t, stats)          # DATA FRAME OF 20 OBS BY 1053 COLUMNS
```

Add same like steps for other nested objects not shown in screenshots. Ultimately, `main_df` should be a data frame of only flat, atomic types of 20 obs by 1053 (24 + 1023) columns.